# How can i backup google cloud sql instance db daily?

Tags: backup, google-cloud-sql

i read the article about cloud sql backup. But cannot understand for how to make daily backups.. how can I make it?

reference : https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/backup-recovery#schedulebackups

Answer (score 0):

Following your link to the documentation the first line quotes:

`Each Google Cloud SQL instance has backups enabled by default, scheduled to run at a time chosen at random`

Backups are run every day at the configured time.